# What does Lazy mean in NHibernate

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to `NHibernate` -also in `EntityFramework`, I'm learning them. I see the `Lazy` keyword in both `NH` and `EF`, but I can't understand it. How you can explain `Lazy` for a five years old? It seems to be important. Can you explain it in simple words please?

**UPDATE:**

In **NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code**, we have:

```
ManyToOne(t => t.SomeProperty, t => t.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy));
```

that `LazyRelation` has this static values:

```
public abstract class LazyRelation {
    public static LazyRelation Proxy;
    public static LazyRelation NoProxy;
    public static LazyRelation NoLazy;
}
```

What does means each of them? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lazy loading is a technique used by ORMs (such as EF, NH and Linq2SQL) whereby related entities in a hierarchy are not retrieved immediately. Instead, related entities are only fetched if they are needed, typically when they are 'navigated to' or dereferenced.

e.g. In a class model, you might have a class `Person`, which has a `Collection` (e.g. `IEnumerable`) of `Pets` which he / she owns.

If you use lazy loading when you fetch the Person, then the related Pets collection will not be fetched at the same time. This way, database and memory resources are conserved.

However, if the Pets collection IS accessed (and assuming the Context / Session of the ORM is still available), then the ORM will go and fetch the Pets on an 'as needed' basis.

Compare this to Eager loading (e.g. `LoadsWith` L2SQL or `Include` EF) where the caller explicitly states which of the related entities will be fetched along with the Person.

See also here : [Lazy loading, Deferred Loading and Eager Loading in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230508/lazy-loading-deferred-loading-and-eager-loading-in-entity-framework)

**Re Update**
Ayende explains why you would use no-proxy lazy loading (versus proxy lazy loading) [here](http://ayende.com/blog/4378/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations).
NoLazy disables lazy loading (i.e. eager loaded)

You can read up more on the techniques used to [implement lazy loading on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). 
NH's Proxy pattern implementation is discussed [here](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/)

Answer (score 2):

Lazy means it create the property of an object only when it has been accessed once.
This way you can instanciate thousands of object wich don't use memory, they are just reference to empty objects, until you use them.