# EF difference in eager loading and lazy loading?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I'm new to EF and have read some articles. After reading I got confused in what is difference between lazy loading and eager loading?

- Can both type of queries be compiled?
- Can both type of queries return `IQuerable` and `IEnumerable`?
- Can both type of queries have Linq to Entities query syntex (select, from, where) and lambda expressions?

Kindly guide and help me.

Thanks a lot for your time and guidance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy loading, Deferred Loading and Eager Loading in Entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230508/lazy-loading-deferred-loading-and-eager-loading-in-entity-framework)

Comment: I think using `.Include` in your query makes it immediate loading, maybe you could control by using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can both type of queries be compiled?

Only eager loading can be part of manually pre-compiled query. Lazy loading query is automatically created by EF and it is EF internal behavior if it actually pre-compiles it.

> Can both type of queries return IQuerable and IEnumerable?

In eager loading you can control if the query returns `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`. Lazy loading query happens out of your control and you cannot modify it. If you want to use `IQueryable` for lazily loaded navigation properties you must use third option called explicit loading where you get `IQueryable` query for given navigation property and you can modify it.

> Can both type of queries have Linq to entities queries syntax (select,
>   from, where) and lambda expressions?

No. Neither of these queries have select, from, where. Lazy loading happens out of your control and eager loading doesn't allow filtering - in both cases you always load all related objects.

Example of explicit query (the only type of loading where you can use query):

```
var query = ((EntityCollection<MyEntity>)parent.Children).CreateSourceQuery()
                                                         .Where(...);
```

Answer (score 8):

About the difference between **lazy** and **eager** loading:

Suppose you have a `Customer` object with has a property `List<Invoice> Invoices` (which is in a different table and joined automatically by the Entity Framework).

With `lazy` loading the invoices won't be fetched immediately when your Customer object is instantiated, but only when you need it / access it explicitely.

With `eager` loading your invoices will be fetched and constructed / filled on the object immediately (which introduces some unnecessary performance overhead if you build a huge list of Customers but don't really need all the invoices to be readily available on the object).

You'll find some documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx).

Comment: +1 Exactly, which means - if you're not careful - you can run into N+1 problem: you're getting the `Customer` object and then you want to iterate over the `Invoices`. That means you'll make 1 call to the DB for the customer, and N calls for all the Invoices, since they're fetched one-by-one. That's when you `Include` the `Invoices` in the original query to eagerly fetch them in one DB call.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading is only loading related objects at the moment this is actually needed, eager loading is the opposite of this. The choice of strategy could have a big impact on performance, e.g. loading a big dataset when you don't actually need it.