# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" even when I checked null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reference, null

I have `Room` and `Bed` EF classes which each of `Room` have some `Bed`s.when I use this LINQ statement:

```
IEnumerable<Room> room=...
if (room == null || !room.Any())
    return null;
return room.SelectMany(r=>r.Beds);
```

give me this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in `return` line.

Comment: So maybe there is at least 1 room with `Beds==null`

Comment: Thinking isn't good enough, you should know. Or find out.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I only have one `Room` with two `Beds` in it

Comment: Your code looks OK and shouldn't give this error. So try to reproduce it in a small but complete program we can run as well. Most likely you'll find the cause yourself along the way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of your rooms in the enumerable is null. Do this:

```
return room.Where(r => r != null)
           .SelectMany(r => r.Beds);
```

Comment: for me it was `return room.Where(r => r.Beds != null)
           .SelectMany(r => r.Beds);`

Comment: Anyone knows why this happens? It works when doing room.Select(x => x.beds) when has a null on it, why selectmany doesnt?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my `Collection` of `Room`s were not `null` and also none of `Room`'s `Beds` were `null`. problem was that at least one item of my `Room` `Collection` was `null`. so according to *YK1*'s answer I should use:

```
return room.Where(r => r != null).SelectMany(r => r.Beds);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error can only happen when a Room has `Beds == null`.

You state: "I only have one Room with two Beds in it" but the question also mentions EF.

So the problem is in the `...` in `IEnumerable<Room> room=...`.

When your EF query uses [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230508/lazy-loading-deferred-loading-and-eager-loading-in-entity-framework) the Beds property will be null even if there are records.

For a complete solution you'll have to post all details about the EF part: Code|DB first, the query, which type Context class, EF version etc.

With the latest versions of EF this kind of problem is rare, my guess is that you have a `ToList()` in the query where you shouldn't.

Comment: but why `if(!room.Any(x => x.Beds == null))` give me same error?

Comment: I don't really know. Unable to tell from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use count too, like this:

```
IEnumerable<Room> room=...
if (room == null)    // Check for nulls
       return null;
else if (room.count() == 0)     // Check if empty
       return null;
else if(!room.Any(x => x.Beds == null)      // Check if there is no null Beds
       return room.SelectMany(r=>r.Beds);
```

Comment: A lot of checking but what could be the real cause?

Comment: The count() == 0 would be to replace the !room.Any() i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
return room.Where(r => r != null & r.Beds != null).SelectMany(r => r.Beds);
```