# LINQ Group Query Slow

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

For some reason a lot of my Linq queries are taking forever. When I run this query in TOAD with equivalent SQL it takes about 10 seconds. Other queries I am needing to run are even more complex than this, so it is making me nervous for my users.

When running this from linq and entities framework takes 1 minute, I am really at a loss. Any help you can provide would be great.

```
model.NextYearStructure =(from b in context.BI_b_ACCOUNT_STRUCT
                    join dlr in context.ACCOUNT on b.D_ACCT_KEY equals dlr.ACCT_KEY
                    join sales in context.CBR_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_MV on dlr.ACCT_KEY equals sales.D_ACCT_KEY
                    join org in context.BI_b_SLS_ORG on b.b_ORG_KEY equals org.b_ORG_KEY
                    join dd in context.DATE_DIM on sales.FY_ADJ_DATE_KEY equals dd.DATE_KEY
                    where org.SLS_LVL_2_ID == abmid && org.SLS_LVL_3_ID == dsmid && dd.FY == "2014"
                    group new {
                       org,
                       sales

                    } by new {
                        org.SLS_LVL_3_LAST_NAME,
                        org.SLS_LVL_3_FIRST_NAME,
                        sales.NET_SALES_QTY
                    } into g 
                    select new ViewNyStructure {

                        dsmName = g.Key.SLS_LVL_3_FIRST_NAME + " " + g.Key.SLS_LVL_3_LAST_NAME,
                        TotalSales = g.Sum(x=>x.sales.NET_ORDER_QTY)

                    }).Distinct().AsQueryable();
```

This is how I am rendering the results in `.cshtml`

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Sales</td>
</tr>

@foreach (var NextYear in Model.NextYearStructure)
{  
   <tr>
      <td>
      @NextYear.dsmName 
      </td>
      <td>
      @NextYear.TotalSales
      </td>
   </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Do you run the SQL generated by L2E, or your own hand crafted SQL? Also, are you sure you need the call to `AsQueryable()` at the end? Won't this be an IQueryable already?

Comment: This query is lazy loaded.. how are you using it later when you reference the results?

Comment: What do you mean by lazy loaded?

Comment: This should help you understand Eager vs. Lazy loading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230508/lazy-loading-deferred-loading-and-eager-loading-in-entity-framework

Comment: I am coming to the conclusion that LINQ doesn't handle complex group by queries very efficiently.

Comment: Does my group queries fine. But as with all queries, you need to have to correct indexes. Do you know what query is being generated? Also, does your 10 minute timing include all the processing you do in your code on the result after the Linq statement has been 'executed' (see Josh's Lazy Loading above)?